# How can i add a method to ImageButton which is in loop in asp.net also how can i group the stars in c# side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I am developing an RSS System and each news has 5 stars choice . when i click any stars a method needs to work  and the method has to know where button comes from in order to change the sources of imagebuttons which are down of the same  news

```
                <% for (j = i * 5 + 1; j < (i *5)+6; j++)
        {

            imageid = "Img" + j;

                       %>
                        <div class="yildiz"><asp:ImageButton ID=Imageid runat="server" Height="19px" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/yildiz.png" onclick="ImageButton2_Click" Width="20px" 
                        style="position: relative; top: 13px; left:6px; float:left; "   /></div>


       <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks horrid but..

The simplest way is to use the CommandArgument param of the Image button to store 'j' and your news item id or whatever you need. In your ImageButton2_Click handler cast the sender to an ImageButton then check the CommandArgument for this combo of information and you have what you need.

If you pasted more code - e.g. a sample of how you are emitting your news items - then I can give a quick and dirty code sample.

Comment: not even a command argument won't work..it needs something like a repeater to handle the command event

Comment: Or he could Bind to a method and call the method <a href='<%= SomeMethod() %>/path/page.aspx for example

Comment: Yeah that's why I wanted him to paste his news item generation - I'd imagine a repeater. His code there is just generating stars. Command Argument should be fine if he sets it as part of that ungodly loop..

Comment: Briefly, İ want to reach all stars by grouping and changing src of them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an existing component? It will be easier & you can rest assure it was debugged. Check this one:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Rating/Rating.aspx